# Bookmarks stored on Samsung devices are invisible

Tags: android, device

I'm creating bookmark using the similar to the code as below

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK, "1");
values.put(BookmarkColumns.CREATED, "1311170108");
values.put(BookmarkColumns.DATE, "1311170708"); 
values.put(BookmarkColumns.TITLE, "XDA");
values.put(BookmarkColumns.URL, "http://test.com");
values.put(BookmarkColumns.VISITS, "1");
getContentResolver().insert(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, values);
```

Although this code works very well on emulator and devices like HTC Hero. But when my app try to create bookmark on Samsung Galaxy Gio device , it is not visible in the default browser. Although call to Browser.getAllBookmarks() returns all the bookmarks created by my application but non are visible in default browsers bookmark view.

Samsung device looks like store bookmarks in folder structure where as other Android device store them directly. Unfortunately current bookmark/browser api does not look like supports  for folders in bookmarks.

What could be work around to make bookmark visible on samsung devices also ?

Thanks,

Tushar

Answer (score 0):

Call android.provider.Browser.saveBookmark()

Comment: This will launch the bookmark edit activity. I need to update bookmark without user action.